# tick() method in a digital clock - c#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

For my assignment, we are supposed to create a digital clock. I've been stuck at the 3rd part of the question for a while.
  Here's the question :

> 1. write a **Clock** class to represent a single clock. You can have hours, minutes and seconds as instance variables.You can add a method to print time, assuming it is a digital clock.
> 2. write test class ClockTester and try to create clocks to represent different countries, Print their time.
> 3. Add the below methods to make the clock working better.
>
>    - tick() – it will represent one tick of the clock.
>    - incrementSeconds() - It will increase the time by 1 second.
>    - incrementMinutes() - It will increase the time by 1 minute.
>    - incrementHours() - It will increase the time by 1 hour.

Here's the code I tried, It does print the time of the countries but the tick method does not increment the time. -

Clock class:

```
public class Clock 
{
    //instance variables
    private int hours, minutes, seconds;

    public Clock()
    {
        SetTime(0, 0, 0);
    }

    public Clock(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
    {
        SetTime(hours, minutes, seconds);
    }

    public void SetTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
    {
        if ((seconds >=  0) && (seconds < 60) && (minutes >= 0) && (minutes < 60)
            && (hours >= 0) && (hours < 24)) {
            this.hours = hours;
            this.minutes = minutes;
            this.seconds = seconds;
        }
        else
        {
            this.hours = 0;
            this.minutes = 0;
            this.seconds = 0;
        }

    }

    public int GetHours()
    {
        return hours;
    }

    public int GetMinutes()
    {
        return minutes;
    }

    public int GetSeconds()
    {
        return seconds;
    }

    //Tick()
    public void Tick()
    {
        IncrementSeconds();
        IncrementMinutes();
        IncrementHours();
    }

    //incrementSeconds()
    public void IncrementSeconds()
    {
        seconds++;
        if (seconds > 59)
        {
            seconds = 0;
            IncrementMinutes(); 
        }
    }

    //incrementMinutes()
    public void IncrementMinutes()
    {
        minutes++;
        if (minutes > 59)
        {
            minutes = 0;
            IncrementHours();
        }
    }

    //incrementHours()
    public void IncrementHours()
    {
        hours++;
        if (hours > 23)
        {
            hours = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

clockTester class :

```
public class ClockTester
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //print time in UK - London
        Clock clockUK = new Clock();
        clockUK.SetTime(18, 29, 48);
        Console.WriteLine("London, UK : {0}:{1}:{2}", clockUK.GetHours(), clockUK.GetMinutes(), clockSL.GetSeconds());

        //print time in US - New York
        Clock clockUS = new Clock();
        clockUS.SetTime(13, 29, 48);
        Console.WriteLine("New York, US : {0}:{1}:{2}", clockUS.GetHours(), clockUS.GetMinutes(), clockUS.GetSeconds());

        //print time in Japan - Tokyo
        Clock clockJP = new Clock();
        clockJP.SetTime(02, 29, 48);
        Console.WriteLine("Tokyo, Japan : {0}:{1}:{2}", clockJP.GetHours(), clockJP.GetMinutes(), clockJP.GetSeconds());
    } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I'd say, they just mean the format "HH:MM:SS", like `15:22:57` or something by "digital clock". Please do not post homework questsions here on stackoverflow. If you have a specific problem, i.e. something doesnt work as expected, you may ask. See also [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Homework questions should be dissected first, i.e. try to work out what your being asked to explore or show knowledge of. In this case, you most certainly will end up using Time formatted strings, and you need to overload the ToString method which will teach you about a few things. Hopefully my answer gives you some pointers, although I've left the Time formatting to you, there is a better way than just decimal formatting, but that may be next weeks lesson. Try the simplest form, then more elegant/useful forms. Try to not reinvent the wheel unless specifically asked to.

Comment: There's no code that ever calls `Tick()`, so what do you expect? Why don't you simply write another test that sets a time and calls `Tick()` and then outputs the current time to see it increased by 1 second?

Answer (score 1):

You should have heard of the ToString method/function.

All objects have one in C# because all classes inherit/descend from Object class which defines a tostring method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8  and you can overload the default with your own implementation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#overloading-the-tostring-method

Your ToString function should return a formatted string, look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

e.g.

```
   public class MyTimeClass {

    // fields/variables/properties and other methods not displayed, use imagination!

    public string ToString(){
         return String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}",this.hours, this.minutes, this.seconds, this.ticks);
        //ideally this would be culture dependant/sensitive
    }

}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/uN2H2F

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't match your example.

Comment: Well spotted, it's an abbreviated example as the code comment suggests. Fiddle provided in case the user is unaware of such websites for simple testing/examples of C#

Comment: You are missing the word "override"

Comment: Yeah it's optional depending on usage, and generates a warning accordingly using a good IDE.